# AJAX update MySQL query based on <option> values

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hey. So I am looking for a way to pass an option value through my mySQL query, dynamically. The goal is to simply update the LIMIT value, or the Posts per page in my case. An example of some code would be great, or even just a link to point me in the right direction. I have looked through a few AJAX tutorial, but I am looking for something more specific to my case. Thanks!

Comment: basically you just need to add a value to your post body or as get in ajax-called url and get that int as limit

Comment: are you using any frameworks? I can give you an example if you can point me in the right direction...

Comment: I am not using any framework. Just developing a gallery application as a learning process as I am new to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend looking into and using JQuery

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html

Comment: Thanks. I was actually trying to avoid the use of libraries at this stage of learning.